# How can I access my domain www virtual host via the IP?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ssh

I have a website that runs on an IP, `23.222.22` for example

I have created my virtual host as `/home/www/www.site.com` in Apache as my web server.

However for development, before updating DNS, can I access the site like

```
http://23.222.22/~www.site.com/
```

Because

```
http://23.222.22/ just loads info from var/www
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this seem fine right! What's your question!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't directly

To get what you want:

- Add that entry to your `hosts`* file, where your www.site.com will point to your ip
- You can find a browser plugin, where you can add a `Host` header, to tell the webserver which vhost you wish to access

* `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows and `/etc/hosts` on *nix; just add `23.22.22.22 www.site.com` at the end,  and then open www.site.com in your browser

Comment: Works like a charm. Wanted to run this site in development without touching DNS and this works great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your site as the default DocumentRoot for Apache then it should display that site when you access using an IP rather than the hostname.

Of course all your server variables for URL etc will be the IP rather than the hostname.